# I created textarea expander from script but after, it doesn't expands

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, textarea

I don't know if the title is correct.
I created, with one script, a table with 5 textarea with class="expand".
This textarea when I write expands but then doesn't works.
Is there a method after writing to call the jquery plugin? 
Before i tried without creating the textarea, I wrote in the html file and it worked.

(Info and example on 2 textarea:

```
http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/index.html
http://jsfiddle.net/V2RLs/2/ (without class="expand")
```

)
But after When i write in the textarea it doesn't expands.Why?

This is my script:

```
<script src='js/jquery.textarea-expander.js'></script>
<script >$(document).ready(function() { 
var regex,v,l,c,b;

$( "#wnd_Addparam" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            resizable:false,
            buttons: {
                "Add": function() {
                                 contapara=(parseInt(contapara)+1);

                document.getElementById("sorpara").innerHTML+="<li id=\"inputp"+contapara+"_id\" class=\"ui-state-default\"><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s\"></span>"+txt_idparam.value+"</li>";    
                $('#formp').submit();
                                $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
                                   },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        });

        $( "#btn_Addpar" ).click(function() {
                        i=(parseInt(contapara)+1);

    $('#wnd_Addparam').append('<form method="GET" id="formparam"><table><tr><td><label> ID  </label></td><td><textarea class="expand" id="inputp'+i+'_id" class="text"> </textarea></td></tr><tr><td><label>Type</label></td><td><select id="inputp'+i+'_type"><option value="text">Text</option><option value="integer">Integer</option><option value="float">Float</option><option value="list_values">List of values</option><option value="range">Range</option><option value="selection_collapsed">Selection (collapsed)</option><option value="selection_expanded">Selection (expanded)</option><option value="subimage">Subimage selection</option><option value="polygon">Polygon selection</option><option value="horizontal_separator">Horizontal separator</option></select></td></tr><tr><td> <label > Description</label></td> <td><textarea class="expand" id="inputp'+i+'_description" size=24></textarea></td></tr><tr><td><label>Value</label></td><td><textarea class="expand" id="inputp'+i+'_value"></textarea></td></tr><tr><td><label>Info (help)</label></td><td><textarea class="expand" id="inputp'+i+'_info"></textarea></td></tr><tr><td><label> Visible?</label></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="inputp'+i+'_visible"></td></tr></table>/form>');
                $( "#wnd_Addparam" ).dialog( "open" );
            });});</script>
```

The plugin expander..

```
/**
* TextAreaExpander plugin for jQuery
* v1.0
* Expands or contracts a textarea height depending on the
* quatity of content entered by the user in the box.
*
* By Craig Buckler, Optimalworks.net
*
* As featured on SitePoint.com:
* http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/07/29/build-auto-expanding-textarea-1/
*
* Please use as you wish at your own risk.
*/
/**
* Usage:
*
* From JavaScript, use:
* $(<node>).TextAreaExpander(<minHeight>, <maxHeight>);
* where:
* <node> is the DOM node selector, e.g. "textarea"
* <minHeight> is the minimum textarea height in pixels (optional)
* <maxHeight> is the maximum textarea height in pixels (optional)
*
* Alternatively, in you HTML:
* Assign a class of "expand" to any <textarea> tag.
* e.g. <textarea name="textarea1" rows="3" cols="40" class="expand"></textarea>
*
* Or assign a class of "expandMIN-MAX" to set the <textarea> minimum and maximum height.
* e.g. <textarea name="textarea1" rows="3" cols="40" class="expand50-200"></textarea>
* The textarea will use an appropriate height between 50 and 200 pixels.
*/
(function($) {
// jQuery plugin definition
$.fn.TextAreaExpander = function(minHeight, maxHeight) {
var hCheck = !($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera);
// resize a textarea
function ResizeTextarea(e) {
// event or initialize element?
e = e.target || e;
// find content length and box width
var vlen = e.value.length, ewidth = e.offsetWidth;
if (vlen != e.valLength || ewidth != e.boxWidth) {
if (hCheck && (vlen < e.valLength || ewidth != e.boxWidth)) e.style.height = "0px";
var h = Math.max(e.expandMin, Math.min(e.scrollHeight, e.expandMax))+2;
e.style.overflow = (e.scrollHeight > h ? "auto" : "hidden");
e.style.height = h + "px";
e.valLength = vlen;
e.boxWidth = ewidth;
}
return true;
};
// initialize
this.each(function() {
// is a textarea?
if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "textarea") return;
// set height restrictions
var p = this.className.match(/expand(\d+)\-*(\d+)*/i);
this.expandMin = minHeight || (p ? parseInt('0'+p[1], 10) : 0);
this.expandMax = maxHeight || (p ? parseInt('0'+p[2], 10) : 99999);
// initial resize
ResizeTextarea(this);
// zero vertical padding and add events
if (!this.Initialized) {
this.Initialized = true;
$(this).css("padding-top", 0).css("padding-bottom", 0);
$(this).bind("keyup", ResizeTextarea).bind("focus", ResizeTextarea);
}
});
return this;
};
})(jQuery);
// initialize all expanding textareas
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin prepares textareas on document.ready, so any textarea that this class is assigned to after document.ready fired will not be affected by the plugin - however, you can just call the plugin directly instead of adding the class:

```
jQuery(".expand").TextAreaExpander();
```

However, you should not run TextAreaExpander twice on one element, so be sure to use another classname for the newly generated textareas if you have textareas using the plugin that are initialized on document.ready - alternatively you can delete the last few lines of the plugin.

Comment: This title's question is correct?
Before i delete the lasy few lines but after don't work.
I write after appendTo this sentence:
jQuery("textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander();
The textarea working but become very small.
I edit the question with adding the plugin.

Comment: The default setting of the plugin is to shrink the textarea to the smallest possible size - however, TextAreaExpander supports arguments to set the maximum and minimum vertical size for the textarea. `$.fn.TextAreaExpander = function(minHeight, maxHeight)`

Comment: Excuse me Damon that you answer is correct and interest.
But this variable where are from?

Comment: This is a function definition - `jQuery(".expand").TextAreaExpander(5,10);` would create a textarea with a minimum height of 5 and a maximum of 10.

Comment: $('#wnd_Addparam').find('textarea').TextAreaExpander();
It's sentence for call the new textarea's creating