# The plugin jquery work for one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

This question is the continuation of [I created textarea expander from script but after, it doesn't expands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966162/i-created-textarea-expander-from-script-but-after-it-doesnt-expands/12966219#12966219)
Because i create a table with the textarea and i want call the plugin textarea.
Calling after the appendTo with `jQuery("textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander();`
I searching all the textarea with class="expand" and working.
How to edit this sentence for working only one div's interest?

Comment: Use id instead of class in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your structure is like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <textarea class="expand"></textarea>
</div>
```

You can simply do this:

```
$('#parent > textarea[class*=expand]');
```

`>` is the child selector and `#id`selects the element with the given id.

**Edit**

As @VijayVerma stated in the comments: If your `<div>` doesn't have an ID yet, just add the ID to the textarea instead:

```
<textarea id="onlyme" class="expand"></textarea>
```

And select it with the ID-selector only:

```
$('#onlyme');
```

If your <`div>`s already have IDs, you're fine with the first solution I've posted.

Comment: @user1749285 So it is working fine? Sorry, I didn't really get you as I don't understand what you mean in the second part "*i don't want,i always wrong my question*".

Comment: For caling jQuery("textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander(); using Javascript but only one div without i edit the plugin jquery.
For editing the new creating textarea

Comment: @user1749285 Ok, now I got it. :)

Comment: jQuery(".expand").TextAreaExpander();

Answer (score 0):

give the div an id..let say

```
<div id="YourId"><textarea>..</textarea></div>

jQuery("#YourID > textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander();
```