# Always call function of pluginjquery for textareaexpader

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

This so a continuation of this question: [I created textarea expander from script but after, it doesn't expands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966162/i-created-textarea-expander-from-script-but-after-it-doesnt-expands)

I have the plugin that how write in the textarea after automatic is expand.
This is a plugin:

```
/**
* TextAreaExpander plugin for jQuery
* v1.0
* Expands or contracts a textarea height depending on the
* quatity of content entered by the user in the box.
*
* By Craig Buckler, Optimalworks.net
*
* As featured on SitePoint.com:
* http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/07/29/build-auto-expanding-textarea-1/
*
* Please use as you wish at your own risk.
*/
/**
* Usage:
*
* From JavaScript, use:
* $(<node>).TextAreaExpander(<minHeight>, <maxHeight>);
* where:
* <node> is the DOM node selector, e.g. "textarea"
* <minHeight> is the minimum textarea height in pixels (optional)
* <maxHeight> is the maximum textarea height in pixels (optional)
*
* Alternatively, in you HTML:
* Assign a class of "expand" to any <textarea> tag.
* e.g. <textarea name="textarea1" rows="3" cols="40" class="expand"></textarea>
*
* Or assign a class of "expandMIN-MAX" to set the <textarea> minimum and maximum height.
* e.g. <textarea name="textarea1" rows="3" cols="40" class="expand50-200"></textarea>
* The textarea will use an appropriate height between 50 and 200 pixels.
*/
(function($) {
// jQuery plugin definition
$.fn.TextAreaExpander = function(minHeight=21, maxHeight) {
var hCheck = !($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera);
// resize a textarea
function ResizeTextarea(e) {
// event or initialize element?
e = e.target || e;
// find content length and box width
var vlen = e.value.length, ewidth = e.offsetWidth;
if (vlen != e.valLength || ewidth != e.boxWidth) {
if (hCheck && (vlen < e.valLength || ewidth != e.boxWidth)) e.style.height = "0px";
var h = Math.max(e.expandMin, Math.min(e.scrollHeight, e.expandMax))+2;
e.style.overflow = (e.scrollHeight > h ? "auto" : "hidden");
e.style.height = h + "px";
e.valLength = vlen;
e.boxWidth = ewidth;
}
return true;
};
// initialize
this.each(function() {
// is a textarea?
if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "textarea") return;
// set height restrictions
var p = this.className.match(/expand(\d+)\-*(\d+)*/i);
this.expandMin = minHeight || (p ? parseInt('0'+p[1], 10) : 0);
this.expandMax = maxHeight || (p ? parseInt('0'+p[2], 10) : 99999);
// initial resize
ResizeTextarea(this);
// zero vertical padding and add events
if (!this.Initialized) {
this.Initialized = true;
$(this).css("padding-top", 0).css("padding-bottom", 0);
$(this).bind("keyup", ResizeTextarea).bind("focus", ResizeTextarea);
}
});
return this;
};
})(jQuery);
// initialize all expanding textareas
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander();
});
```

When I open my site and when I open this plugin. I call the function `TextAreaExpander()` takes all the textarea with `class="expand"` and change the parameters.
Up to functioning here.

After I create new textarea with this class( using `Jquery and Javascript`) but i don't know, how to call the function `TextAreaExpander()`

There is one method that is `jQuery(".expand").TextAreaExpander();` and write on the last three sentence for change all textarea.
This don't function.

How to change the plugin to change the old and new textarea?

I did one other operation .
After I create the new textarea, i can call the function with `jQuery(".expand").TextAreaExpander();` and function.
But I calling this function three times that is in three function different and now doesn't function and i have new error.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jQuery(".expand").TextAreaExpander()')
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario is not uncommon whereby you call a plugin on page load, then add new elements that require same plugin. If you call the plugin on the whole class you can run into problems since it has already been initialized on existing eleemnts

Several things you could do

1. Modify plugin to add a class like "textAreaExpander" then check to  see if that class already exists when plugin runs. If it exists, do    nothing.  -OR-
2. Only call the plugin on the new html as in following example

.

```
var $newElement= $('<textarea>').appendTo( selector);
$newElement.TextAreaExpander()
```

Comment: Thanks...And now i change my script

Comment: you are defining `$newEleemnt` as `$('#wnd_Addparam')` and you left `$` out of variable name at end. You can also do: `$('#wnd_Addparam').find('textarea').TextAreaExpander()` after the append